# which one to use 'will open' vs 'is open' for future?

Tags: adjectives, future-tense, past-participles

Which one is correct or wrong? Can you please explain in detail?

1. The shop will open tomorrow.
2. The shop is open tomorrow.
3. The shop will be open tomorrow.
4. The shop will be opened tomorrow.

And one last:

1. You have to come to the office tomorrow.
2. You will have to come to the office tomorrow.

Which one is correct in above two and why?

Comment: Also ***...is opening*** and ***...will be opening***. Not to mention ***...is going to open, is going to be opening,*** etc. But it's already "Too Broad" as it is.

Comment: ...shall open, shall be open, shall be opened...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first set of statements

> The shop will open tomorrow
> The shop will be opened tomorrow

implies it will be closed tonight and then will re-open tomorrow

> The shop is open tomorrow
> The shop will be open tomorrow

are both neutral about what is happening to it tonight, it may close over night, it may not

Your second pair are more complicated as they normally mean the same but it may be that currently you have no such obligation and in that case the second one would be used followed by the condition. So for example

> You will have to come to the office tomorrow if Chris calls in sick

The other option might be used but in that context seems less natural.