# The new supermarket IS TO BE OPENED by... or WILL BE OPENED by...?

Tags: passive-voice, future-time

> 1. The new supermarket is to be opened by...
> 2. The new supermarket will be opened by...

I'm doing grammar exercises from the book DESTINATION C1 and my answer was the 2nd option because I think it really suits better. However it's not the correct answer, yet there's no explanation and I'd like one please.

Comment: Is that the entire sentence?  Because I can see using either of them, depending on context.

Comment: Hi Maria and welcome to ELL!  There is not enough context for us to answer.  Both sentences are grammatical but they are used in different situations.  Can you provide more details?  Is there more to the sentence?

Comment: The construction **is to be** fits better with official/formal/important/state occasions and individuals. The supermarket **is to be opened** by the mayor but the staff **will be** present. This is a matter of style and propriety, - it sets the right tone - not of grammar. (PS avoid comments such as **hahaha**.)

Comment: The answer written by mdewey for  [which one to use 'will open' vs 'is open' for future?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/258762/9161) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You have run across a bad example in your workbook. Both phrases are completely grammatical, but the second one sounds much more natural. It's not that unusual for language learning texts to have problems like this, especially when the author is themselves a non-native speaker.